# Hard coded path: how do I link it on a ASP.NET MVC website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url

I have a PDF document in the following location on the remote web server:

C:\Domains\Bin\Invoices\1000.pdf

How do I link it? I tried:

```
string rootPath = Server.MapPath("~");
string path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(rootPath, "..\\Bin\\Invoices"));

<p>@Html.Raw("<a href='"+ path + "\\" + "1000.pdf'>Original PDF copy</a>")</p>
```

Without success: the browser tooltip shows me `file:///C:/domains/bin/invoices/1000.pdf`

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Solved using Joe suggestion, this way:

```
public FileResult InvoiceInPdf(string id)
{
    string rootPath = Server.MapPath("~");
    string path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(rootPath, "..\\Bin\\Invoices\\"));

    return File(path + id + ".pdf", "application/pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a hyperlink to browse to a file at an arbitrary location on the server.  Which is a good thing, as the security of your web server would otherwise be compromised.

You should create an Action that streams the file you want by returning a FileResult.  Google will provide you with examples of this approach.